# Why would two iPhones (5c and 5s) display a Wordpress plugin differently?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, wordpress, compatibility

I'm porting an html site to wordpress (plugin) and I'm running into a unusual issue (for me, at least). The html version of the website looks correct on both iphones, but the wordpress version only looks correct on the 5s. The 5c is showing an incorrect margin-bottom.

Also, I should note that viewing the page on chrome's iphone 5 emulator displays the page correctly.

I'm not looking for anyone to solve this problem for me, i.e. point out any errors in my code. Rather I'm wondering if anyone can provide some insight into why these two phones would be rendering the page differently only in the Wordpress version.

The 5c isn't up to date with the current iOs, but I don't see why that would make a difference? I'm updating right now, just to be sure, but if that's the solution, then I worry about iOS compatibility. Thoughts?

Comment: Update and report back. I think it has something to do with CSS/JS being deferred. Wordpress doesn't like when you mess with script load order.

Comment: Could be different versions of the same browser. You are using the same browser on both phones when talking about the difference right? Without any code it's hard for to investigate and offer insightful suggestions.

Comment: @Switz - Updating the OS fixed the problem! Though I have absolutely no grasp on why. Care to explain what you mean by CSS/JS being deferred? Also, what is the best practice for compatibility issues like this? I'm sure that there are plenty who haven't updated their OS.

Comment: @hungerstar - Yes, I was using Safari on both, but different OS versions so I assume that also means different Safari versions, yeah? The different browser version idea crossed my mind, but since the HTML version of the site runs correctly on each phone I thought it had to be a Wordpress issue. Thanks for providing as much as you could without any code to look at!

Comment: @PenVirus - It just means moving scripts from the header to footer to decrease load time. This is all well and good for most sites but not wordpress because of the multiple css calls that rely upon loaded js and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the operating system fixed the margin on the problematic iPhone. I cleared the cache before the update to make sure that wasn't the case. I'm half relieved to have solved the problem but half worried that anyone with an older OS will be looking at an ugly design. How seriously should one take OS version compatibility for issues like this?

Thanks to everyone for their input!

Edit - Switz provided a helpful explanation for why Wordpress may be creating problems when the HTML version of the site did not. I'll quote it here for visibility:

"Update and report back. I think it has something to do with CSS/JS being deferred. Wordpress doesn't like when you mess with script load order."

"It just means moving scripts from the header to footer to decrease load time. This is all well and good for most sites but not wordpress because of the multiple css calls that rely upon loaded js and vice versa"

Answer (score 0):

Do the phones run different versions of the OS? I setup my own personal website ([www.epic-apps.uk](http://www.epic-apps.uk))* using Wordpress, and from my experience I've never worked with such a buggy system. The best solution I've found when encountering random problems like this is to contact their support team directly. I've also noticed that a lot of the bugs I see where due to caching from previous versions. You can try clearing all contents and data from safari on both your phones and then try to look at the websites again.

Comment: Yes, they did run different OS versions. I updated the problematic iPhone to the new OS and that did the trick.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow...I tried upvoting but it said I need a reputation of at least 15?

Comment: I see, in that case you can mark the answer as correct.